# Issue with amazon elastic bean stalk in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on Amazon (AWS). I have downloaded and installed the AWSCLI and AWSEBS executables but am getting the error:

> "eb is not recognize" as an internal or external command line.

I read the documentation on the Amazon site, but cannot rectify the issue.

Comment: Please Join screenshots and other information like from where did you download, your OS and any clue that can help other to answer your question!!

Answer (score 0):

You  did not specify the operating system  you are  working on, but since you mentioned "command line" let me assume its  windows operating system. Hope you have Python installed on the system, and added to the system path?. In my  experience to rectify the issue, i typed asw cli or aws eb on the cmd commandline.

[image]